# Cognito "invalid state"

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, okta

I'm trying to use Okta as an identity provider and AWS Cognito for its user pools.  I'm using OIDC and whenever I use the Okta chiclet (or the link Okta shows) to connect, I get the message "An error was encountered with the requested page." with error?null in the url.  I can't figure out what the "invalid state" message is given by Cognito.  Has anyone encountered this before?

***Okta***

SPA
Allowed grant types: authorization code and Implicit

Login redirect URI: 
https://my-custom-domain.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse

Login initiated by Okta or App

Login Flow: Send ID Token directly to app

Scopes: Profile and Email

Initiate login URI: http://localhost:8080/oauth2

***Cognito Active OIDC Provider***

Attributes request method: GET

Authorize scope: openid profile email

issuer: https://my-dev-account.okta.com

***Cognito App client***

Enabled Identity Providers: (all selected)

Callback URL(s): http://localhost:8080/oauth2

Allowed OAauth Flows: Authorization code grant and Implicit grant

Allowed OAuth scopes: email profile openid

Comment: Do you still need help with this question? Can I ask how you are initiating the flow in Okta?